# Springboot with Sybase server - Cannot load driver class: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver

Tags: json, maven, spring-boot, sybase, restful-url

Facing difficulty in configuring Sybase server with a fresh Spring boot application. Not sure how to configure Sybase server with spring boot successfully. Getting error "Cannot load driver class: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver".

Basically, I am looking to fetch some data from Sybase database and post as RESTful service in JSON format. Any help would be appreciated.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.rbccm.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbootpoc1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <name>springbootpoc1</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
            <version>7.07</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8090

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.databasePlatform=org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# hikariCP
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:server:port/dbname
spring.datasource.username=u_****
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.connectionTestQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.poolName=SpringBootHikariCP
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=10
spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=60000
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver

# Number of ms to wait before throwing an exception if no connection is available.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
# Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
# Validate the connection before borrowing it from the pool.
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true

#JDBC customize
spring.jdbc.template.max-rows=500
```

Maven build logs

```
2018-04-04 14:48:25.206 ERROR 21768 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
```

Comment: why is  the scope of the sybase driver set to `provided`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved:** In pom dependency, instead of jpa, I used jdbc. And had to add 'jconn4d.jar' in the classpath externally.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency> 

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
            <version>7.07</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
    <groupId>jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:<server>:<port>/<dbname>
spring.datasource.username=u_****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
```

Comment: With the solution above, you don't need the dependency on `jtds`, since you are not using the JDBC driver that ships with it. You are using JConn's `com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver` while the driver name that comes with jtds is `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 6):

You can use spring boot jpa with sybase following this steps:

1.-Download jconn4.jar from [the sap marketplace](https://store.sap.com/sap/cpa/ui/resources/store/html/SolutionDetails.html?pid=0000014063&catID=DBT&pcntry=US&sap-language=EN&_cp_id=id-1545645876941-0)

2.-Install the jar in your local repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="path-to\jconn4.jar" -DgroupId=sybase -DartifactId=jconn -Dversion=4_RELEASE -Dpackaging=jar
```

3.-Add the dependency to your pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>sybase</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn</artifactId>
            <version>4_RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

4.-Add the database configuration to your application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:HOST:PORT/DB_NAME
spring.datasource.username=USER
spring.datasource.password=PASS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=SCHEMA

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.databasePlatform=org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect
spring.datasource.connectionTestQuery=select 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! Also for people who have a different/newer version of Sybase, don't forget to change it in the pom.xml and application.properties. For example, for jconn2.jars, in application.properties, it should be spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3497/agqkg/index.html

Answer (score 0):

also because `com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver` is not the name of the JDBC driver implementation provided by jtds. The correct name that comes with it is

```
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

I believe jconn4d.jar is not on maven central, and the driver name that ships with this implementation is `com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver`

for more details are on:

```
https://www.dbvis.com/features/sybase-ase-database-drivers/

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#driverImplementation
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. Spring JPA worked for me

1.Added the Jconn3.jar(you can even add latest version of it) in resources folder.

2.Modified connection-test query in application.properties

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:<server>:<port>/<dbname>
spring.datasource.username=u_****
spring.datasource.password=*****
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue bugged me a little bit, but its solution is quite easy.
First in your pom.XML add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

then your URL definition should follow this format (in Application.properties or Application.yml)

```
jdbc:jtds:sybase://<Host>:<Port>/<database>
```

this solution should work well.